# Java: Game of Life - issue with neighbours

Tags: java

I'm new to this forum so I hope I'm posting this question in the right way - otherwise, please let me know.

I'm trying to write the code for a simple Game of Life animation in Java, and most of it seems to work as intended.
However, there is a problem with one of the neighbour 'rules' that is supposed to "kill" a cell if it has less than 2 neighbours, meaning that cells can have one or no neighbours and still survive - can be seen here: http://peecee.dk/upload/view/435109. All other rules seem to work fine.

Can anyone help me figure out why it ignores the rule (Live cells are equal to '1', dead to '0'.):

```
if (this.state[i][j] == 1 &&
    liveNeighbours(i, j) > 3 || liveNeighbours(i, j) < 2) {
                    this.tempState[i][j] = 0;
```

Thanks a ton in advance!

The code is as follows:

---

```
import java.util.*;

public class GameOfLife {
    private int[][] state;
    private int[][] tempState;

    //Constructor that creates n x n grid of randomly placed live cells
    public GameOfLife(int n) {
        this.state = new int[n+2][n+2];
        this.tempState = new int[n+2][n+2];
        createRandomBoard(n);
    }

    //Sets up the initial state
    public void createRandomBoard(int n) {
        //Creates (n+2) x (n+2) grid of dead cells
        for (int i = 0; i < n+2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n+2; j++) {
                this.state[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        //Creates n x n grid of randomly placed live cells. Live cells are equal to '1', dead to '0'.
        for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < n + 1; j++) {
                int a = (int)Math.round(Math.random());
                this.state[i][j] = a;
            }
        }
        drawBoard();
    }

    //Draws the live cells as dots based on current state
    public void drawBoard() {
        StdDraw.show(50);
        StdDraw.clear();
        for (int i = 1; i < this.state.length-2; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < this.state.length-2; j++) {
                StdDraw.setXscale(1,this.state.length-3);
                StdDraw.setYscale(1,this.state.length-3);
                StdDraw.setPenRadius((double)1/this.state.length);
                if (this.state[i][j] == 1) {
                    StdDraw.point(i, j);
                }
            }
        }
        StdDraw.show(50);
    }

    //Determines which cells live or die in the next state
    public void nextState() {

        //Copies the state array to a temporary state(array) during killing/reviving
        for (int i = 1; i < this.state.length-2; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < this.state.length-2; j++) {
                this.tempState[i][j] = this.state[i][j];
            }
        }

        //Kills cells with more than 3 or less than 2 neighbours and revives dead cells with 3 neighbours
        for (int i = 1; i < this.state.length-2; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < this.state.length-2; j++) {
                if (this.state[i][j] == 1 && liveNeighbours(i, j) > 3 || liveNeighbours(i, j) < 2) {
                    this.tempState[i][j] = 0;
                }
                else if (this.state[i][j] == 0 && liveNeighbours(i, j) == 3) {
                    this.tempState[i][j] = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        //Copies the modified temporary state array to the original state(array) again
        for (int i = 1; i < this.state.length-2; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < this.state.length-2; j++) {
                this.state[i][j] = this.tempState[i][j];
            }
        }

        drawBoard();
    }

    //Counts the number of live neighbours to a cell
    private int liveNeighbours(int x, int y) {
        int numLiveNeighbours = 0;
        for (int i = x-1; i < x+2; i++) {
            for (int j = y-1; j < y+2; j++) {
                if (this.state[i][j] == 1) {
                    numLiveNeighbours++;
                }
            }
        }
        numLiveNeighbours --;
        return numLiveNeighbours;
    }



    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.deepToString(this.state);
    }

    public int[][] getState() {
        return this.state;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know if this helps a lot, but I once made a simple GameOfLive-implementation for python a while ago. In case you know python, this might help you as a ressource :-) https://github.com/Christian1984/GameOfLife/blob/master/gameoflife.py

Comment: I just started to learn Java as my 1st programming language, so I'm afraid I can't read python much :) Thanks anyway, though!

Answer (score 4):

Your condition doesn't seem to express what you want. You need to change it to:

```
if (this.state[i][j] == 1 && (liveNeighbours(i, j) > 3 || liveNeighbours(i, j) < 2))
```

Check [operators precedence rules in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). You were killing those cells being alive and having more than 3 neighbours or those cells with less than two of them.

With this change you will be killing those cells alive and with more than 3 or less than 2 neighbours.

I think your liveNeighbours has a little flaw too: Your are counting (x,y) neighbours and (x,y) itself. You should change it for:

```
private int liveNeighbours(int x, int y) {
        int numLiveNeighbours = 0;
        for (int i = x-1; i < x+2; i++) {
            for (int j = y-1; j < y+2; j++) {
                if (this.state[i][j] == 1 && (x != i || j != y)) {
                    numLiveNeighbours++;
                }
            }
        }
        return numLiveNeighbours;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer!
Unfortunately it does not seem to do any difference :(
I can even split them up into 2 separate statements, and it still does not work.
Any more suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: @user3484724 I see another problem with your code: Your liveNeighbours is counting not only the neighbours but the center cell too. I'll edit my answer to include that fact.

Comment: Thanks again!
I thought I had that fixed by writing:
numLiveNeighbours --;
inside that liveNeighbours method?
Also, it should still work for cells that have no neighbours at all, even if this issue was present (since 1 < 2).

Comment: @user3484724 The problem with always decreasing liveNeighbours is that it will be descreased even when that cell have not been counted because it was dead.

Comment: Ah, I see. Good point - fixed that now :) 
I would still like to be able to kill cells with < 2 neighbours, if anyone can spot the problem.